# Problemas con sello de seguridad https en mi página

Tags: codeigniter, url

tengo un problema.

*¿Cómo pongo el sello de seguridad en mi página web?*

Ya lo compre, pero no se pone el sello de seguridad en el index.
En el **https://www.mipagina.mx** (supongamos que este es como la dirección de mi index). Me sale así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero como tiene varias secciones la página, si me meto a las demás secciones si me sale el sello de seguridad.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*¿Cómo se lo pongo a mi primera página?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto es un problema derivado de que dentro de tu página tienes es algún recurso al que se accede por protocolo no seguro (http://) revisa tu web busca dicho recurso y debes cargarlo en https://